# AngularJS posts sitemap.xml

Tags: angularjs, sitemap

I have a static angular website that hosts on AWS s3 bucket and fetch blog posts from external API server. And I wonder how do I can create sitemap for this static web-pages ?

I have the following type of links:

**blog.com/**  - list of articles

**blog.com/:id/** - article detail

I created simple sitemap:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>http://blog.com/</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

But how do I handle post detail pages ? Or it is fine and google will do this automatically ?

P.S I published my page, but seems google don't see detail pages and don't want index them.